# New Relic Connections Per Server

Tags: performance-monitoring

Using New Relic I am trying to understand the relationship between simultaneous connections and server performance via new relic. As an example of the relationship I would like to see, it would be average pageview load time across a histogram of unique sessions in a particular period (i.e. how did things run with 10 versus 100 versus 1000 other connections).   I am new to new relic and have got some queries around uniquecount of sessions in a particular period, but, having trouble connecting it back to the server information or to some aggregate like the page time from APM.

Thoughts on this query or other things I could do to see this relationship in a production environment?

Comment: Intended to be a "how to generate this report from new relic" rather than a generic capacity planning tool.  I will take it up on the new relic forums